# RxJS Observable that emits in a date range?

Tags: rxjs, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, rxjs5, rxjs6

Is there an observable in RxJS that emits in a date range?

For instance, `interval(1000)` would emit every second. I could use this to check the current date, but I didn't know if RxJS (or JavaScript really) has a method I could hook into that emits when subscribed based on if I'm in a certain date range or at a specific time like October 1st, 2019 at midnight.

Comment: RxJS doesn't but you can calculate the remaining time yourself and use `timer(X)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `takeWhile` or `skipWhile` combine with timestamp to make a scheduler

```
schedule=(date)=>{
    let timeStamp=Math.round(date/1000)
    interval(1000).pipe(
    takeWhile(()=>Math.round(Date.now()/1000)===timeStamp))
}
```